# Content Editable Field not working in PHP but works in HTML

Tags: php, html, contenteditable

OK I know the code for editable field working in HTML, inline edit. But I am unable to use the same i PHP code

I am attaching below HTML working one and PHP in echo where I am lacking

Please Guide

Thanks

***HTML (WORKING)***

```
<td style="text-align:center;" contenteditable="true" data-old_value="<?php echo $row1["view"];?>"  onBlur="saveInlineEdit(this,'view','<?php echo $row1["id"]; ?>')" onClick="highlightEdit(this);"><?php echo $row1["view"]; ?></td>
```

***PHP (Surely there is a mistake by me - Not Working)***

```
echo "<td style='text-align:center;' contenteditable='true' data-old_value='<?php echo $row1["view"];?>'  onBlur='saveInlineEdit(this,"view","<?php echo $row1["id"]; ?>")' onClick='highlightEdit(this);'><?php echo $row1["view"]; ?></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<?php echo` is only used when you're in HTML output mode and need to get back  into PHP execution. But you're already executing PHP. It doesn't do anything special inside a string, it's just echoed literally.

Just use normal variable substitution or concatenation.

```
echo "<td style='text-align:center;' contenteditable='true' data-old_value='{$row1["view"]}'  onBlur='saveInlineEdit(this,\"view\",\"{$row1["id"];\")' onClick='highlightEdit(this);'>{$row1["view"]}</td>
```

Also, you need to escape the literal `"` inside the string.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that the excepted answer will work, atleast one " is missing. I also prefer concatenation, since it is better readable.
Concatenation:

```
echo '<td style="text-align:center;" contenteditable="true" data-old_value="' . $row["notess"] . '" onBlur="saveInlineEdit(this,\"notess\",' . $row["id"] . ')" onClick="highlightEdit(this);">' . $row["notess"] . '</td>';
```

you could also go the dirty way with output buffering:

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<td style="text-align:center;" contenteditable="true" data-old_value="<?php echo $row1["view"];?>"  onBlur="saveInlineEdit(this,'view','<?php echo $row1["id"]; ?>')" onClick="highlightEdit(this);"><?php echo $row1["view"]; ?></td>
<?php ob_end_clean(); ?>
```